# Выборка mongodb, mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

есть запрос

```
this.Model.find({}, null, { skip: from - 1, limit: limit + 1,
}).exec();
```

как сделать сортировку выбранных данных которые получены в запросе, а не всех

Comment: отсортируй их после выполнения запроса штатным sort

Comment: вы имеете ввиду метод js ? Потому что такой запрос this.contractorsModel.find({}, null, { skip: from - 1, limit: limit + 1,
    }).sort({"field": 1}).exec();
сортирует все данные

Comment: да, метод js применённый к результату exec